# How to display two column layout in IE contenteditable element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, contenteditable

I am working on a contenteditable element in which I need to show some content in two column layout. User should be able to place cursor anywhere in text and should also be able to move from one position to other using arrow keys.

I am using `column-count` css to display content in two columns. It works well in other browsers but in IE11, whenever I click on column, a box appears. Also arrow keys are restricted inside the column layout.

I have created a sample example at https://jsfiddle.net/rex3c3yf/. Any JS or CSS solution is welcome

**Problem in IE11**[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using contenteditable="true" for each p tag inside your div.
You can specify them individually for each tag or you can use javascript to add contenteditable=true for all p tags inside your div.